# Creating a configurable user menu (Button selection option)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need you help, I am creating an app, I have 3 views created:
View 1 has 3 buttons
view 2 has 10 buttons

I want the buttons of view 1 to be configurable, i.e. the user can select what buttons to have on view one by selecting them from view 2. I was thinking of doing this with a massive if statement but not sure how you can replace a instance of a button with an other button.

I am not sure that this is the best way to go about it so any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of available buttons and an array of chosen buttons, them simply move buttons between the two arrays depending on whether the user wants them on the view or not.

Then you can iterate the array and automatically lay out the buttons, advancing x and y position where required in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new to this and although have created simple arrays this seems quiet advanced especially with the x and y positioning. I will try to figure it out, fingers crossed.

Comment: Take a look at the box layout code from my article which shows an example.... http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/keeping-things-simple-the-dynamic-box-model/